# Modified configuration is written into a different config.file

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm reading values from an app.config file. After some changes have been made, I'm saving the configuration. Problem is that the changes are being written to a different file.

Values are being read from GeoBagHostingService.exe.config.
Changes are being written to GeoBagService.dll.config

My solution contains 2 projects: GeoBagHostingService and GeoBagService so that's probably where things get mixed up.

Functionally what I want to do is to replace a password value with an encrypted value. So if config contains a "password" key I replace it with a "encryptedPassword" key containing the encrypted password value.

The code I'm using is contained in a class in de GeoBAGService project.

To read, modify and save the configuration I use:

```
// Opening the configuration (GeoBagHostingService.exe.config)
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var oraclePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oraclePassword"];

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oraclePassword))
   {
     string encryptedPassword = EncryptString(oraclePassword, configPassword);
     configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("oraclePassword");
     configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("encryptedPassword");
     configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("encryptedPassword", encryptedPassword);

     // Writing back the changes (or so I thought)
     // encryptedPassword is now in GeoBagService.dll.config
     configuration.Save();
   }

else 
   { 
     oraclePassword = DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["encryptedpassword"], configPassword); 
   }
```

What's happening here and how to write the changes to the same configuration as from where they are being read?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` depends on the place where you call it from.

If you call it in your main project (application), then it will return:

> [MainProjectPath]\[MainProjectName].exe

If you call it from another project (class library), then it will return:

> [LibProjectPath]\[LibProjectName].dll

That's why you're getting those results.

Comment: Hi thanks, What would explain that this happens in a single execution of the same block of code? I read from file A and write to file B. Code being called just once from one place.

Comment: @Rene that's because ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oraclePassword"] always reads from the default app config file (exe)